# Search option and Log button missing in Lightning for Outlook- Mac users

Tags: lightning, salesforce-for-outlook, lightning-outlook, lightning-for-outlook

Our Mac users are experiencing an issue with 'Search' option missing in Outlook plugin. And when they drill down on record, even 'Log' button is missing. But 'Log Email' button is enabled on home page. it's weird and I don't see anyone facing this issue in SF communities.
I removed and reinstalled the Add-ins and no luck. please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. It is caused by Outlook Versions above 16.22. 
For the solution you need to upgrade Outlook on Mac to at least 16.24 which at the moment is only possible through the Office Inside Update Program.

The article offers some solutions
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000paajQAA

Comment: @double-beep This post has been updated accordingly. If you are the user who downvoted this post, you may wish to consider removing or reversing it.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I don't have enough reputation to downvote yet. This answer was detected by SmokeDetector [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49861092#49861092); that's why it caught my attention at all.

Comment: Gotcha, I didn't check your rep. Well, thanks for chiming in and letting this user know how to improve their post. Always good to see constructive criticism affect a positive change. Cheers!

Comment: @Maximilian  - We had opened a Case for this issue and SF offered same solution. I had forgotten about this post. Thanks for answering.!!